# Knex.js : How to select columns from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, query-builder, knex.js

Example query,

```
SELECT a.driverID, a.dCarID, a.dDeviceID, b.carRegiNum FROM driverProfile a, carProfile b WHERE a.dManagerID = 7 AND b.carID=a.dCarID
```

Query runs fine on MySQL. driverProfile and carProfile are two separate tables. 
Please comment if you need more clarification. I am stuck here.

Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original Query (divided into row so we can read it [*hint*])

```
SELECT a.driverID, a.dCarID, a.dDeviceID, b.carRegiNum 
FROM driverProfile a, carProfile b 
WHERE a.dManagerID = 7 AND b.carID=a.dCarID
```

**Step 1, Join Syntax (fix it!)**

Over 25 years ago SQL best practice in joins was redefined and we stopped using commas between table names. **Just stop it**... please! *and you can't do it in Knex.js anyway*.... so best get used to it. Fix the join syntax first:

```
SELECT a.driverID, a.dCarID, a.dDeviceID, b.carRegiNum 
FROM driverProfile a
INNER JOIN carProfile b ON b.carID=a.dCarID
WHERE a.dManagerID = 7
```

**Step 2, Aliases (not)**

It also seems that Knex doesn't do aliases easily, so replace with table names:

```
SELECT driverProfile.driverID, driverProfile.dCarID, driverProfile.dDeviceID, carProfile.carRegiNum 
FROM driverProfile
INNER JOIN carProfile ON carProfile.carID=driverProfile.dCarID
WHERE driverProfile.dManagerID = 7
```

**Step 3, "Knexisfy" the query**

```
knex.select(['driverProfile.driverID', 'driverProfile.dCarID', 'driverProfile.dDeviceID', 'carProfile.carRegiNum' ])
.from('driverProfile')
.innerJoin('carProfile','carProfile.carID','driverProfile.dCarID')
.where('driverProfile.dManagerID',7)
.then(function(output){
    //Deal with the output data here 
});
```

1. http://knexjs.org/#Builder-select
2. http://knexjs.org/#Builder-from
3. http://knexjs.org/#Builder-innerJoin
4. http://knexjs.org/#Builder-where
5. http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-then

Comment: admission: never seen knex before, so that is definitely untested

Comment: It works like a charm. I don't know how to thank you enough. I will dive deep into joins. Thank you again.

Comment: There's heaps of info regarding joins around.  Try this **[visual guide to joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)** and [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Comment: oh, and forget about commas between table names, first rule :)

Comment: This works for that query in specific but in update queries you can't do joins, and if you select by 2 equal tables your query must be aliased.

Comment: @Onza the query for this question is a select statement and joins are freqently needed in those. Not sure why you are mentioning an update statement restriction. It is not all that uncommon for joins to be disallowed in update statements.

Comment: For aliases there is a way to do these refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357228/alias-a-table-in-knex

Comment: @Used_By_Already I mean I came here by googling the question, "How to select columns from multiple tables?" a join is not the same as a select by multiple tables and it's in the SQL standard from rule, sure a join works for this case and it's the best answer for the asker to be honest, it just doesn't cover all possible cases. However if you use a double join to the same table, eg. a one to many relationship you need aliases.

Comment: I think it's not possible to do so with knex, and the only option is knex.raw... since I couldn't find a way to select by multiple tables... (not joining)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  a.driverID, a.dCarID, a.dDeviceID, b.carRegiNum 
FROM 
  driverProfile a, 
  carProfile b 
WHERE 
  a.dManagerID = 7 AND b.carID=a.dCarID
```

With knex 0.14.0:

```
knex({ a: 'driverProfile', b: 'carProfile' })
  .select('a.driverID', 'a.dCarID', 'a.dDeviceID', 'b.carRegiNum')
  .where('a.dManagerID', 7)
  .where('b.carID', knex.raw('??', ['a.dCarID']))
```

Generates (https://runkit.com/embed/b5wbl1e04u0v):

```
select 
  `a`.`driverID`, `a`.`dCarID`, `a`.`dDeviceID`, `b`.`carRegiNum` 
from 
  `driverProfile` as `a`, `carProfile` as `b` 
where 
  `a`.`dManagerID` = ? and `b`.`carID` = `a`.`dCarID`
```